# JavaScript injection minimal example using node/express not working: <script> not executed

Tags: xss, javascript, injection, node.js

I want to create a minimal example where JavaScript injection/XSS is working. This is my example server:

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/index.html"));
});

app.get("/api/comments", (req, res) => {
  res.json(["Comment A", "Comment B<script>console.log('Hello')</script>"]);
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

The browser should execute the script inside Comment B. This is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Comments</h1>
    <ul id="comments"></ul>
    <script>
      fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/comments")
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => renderComments(data));

      function renderComments(comments) {
        let commentHTML = "";
        for (const comment of comments) {
          commentHTML += `<li>${comment}</li>`;
        }
        document.getElementById("comments").innerHTML = commentHTML;
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I can see the script tag with the inspector in the browser however it isn't executed. Nothing is logged into the console. It doesn't work either with alert or fetch. What is missing to get the browser to execute the script inside the comment?

[image: js injection]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are scripts injected through innerHTML not executed whilst onerror and other on<event> attributes on elements are? - Google XSS Challenge 2](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/60861), [Why this XSS payload doesn't work?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/190362/) and [several more](https://www.google.com/search?q=innerhtml+script+not+executed+site%3Asecurity.stackexchange.com)

Comment: As a side note, this has nothing to do with Node.JS, which is a server-side framework. You could do this just fine in PHP, Java, .NET, Ruby, or even just serving static files from Apache or IIS (both written in C/C++) directly. Script injection *into HTML* - that is, as XSS - is a client-side attack (though in the real world fixing it is typically a server-side change).